# Как при использовании встроенного http-сервера Laravel выставить заголовок ответа Access-Control-Allow-Origin для картинок

Tags: laravel, http, cors

Как я понял, при обращении к реальному файлу (картинке) в public запрос не прооходит через ларавеловскую маршрутизацию, и его сразу отдает встроенный hhtp-сервер.

Можно ли как-то настроить этот встроенный сервер так, чтоб он для картинок возвращал

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"**

Или лучше забыть об этом и переводить локальную разработку под Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если обращение к статическим файлам, то настройки должны задаваться на уровне веб-сервера.

Для nginx:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|png|svg|webp)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Для Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   <Directory /var/www/html>
      ...
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      ...
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы помоглит принять правильное решение  - уйти с встроенного сервера.